# Why tcp server can get client's ip?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

Ip message in ip protocol header. When tcp protocol receive a packet, it only has a tcp header, and there is no ip address. Why can we get client's ip address from a socket.

Comment: There is no *"tcp protocol receive a packet"* but there is the network stack of the OS receiving the packet. And this packet contains TCP payload, TCP header, IP header ... - i.e. the clients source IP is contained in the packet.

Comment: The IP header contains the source IP address, and it is available to the TCP server. Indeed it is available to the TCP layer, whatever they may have irrrelevantly taught you in college about OSI.

Comment: tcp protocol does not receive packets, it receives segments

Comment: A TCP connection is identified by both the source and destination network-layer addresses and the source and destination transport-layer addresses. This is clearly spelled out in RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol, which is the definition of TCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is based on IP: it uses IP packets to carry data around the Internet. More specifically, the whole TCP packet is fitted into an IP packet's body before being sent.

So you won't find the IP address in the TCP packet because such information belongs to the IP packet. When the client receives a TCP segment, it receives it inside an IP packet containing the IP address.

Comment: IP has packets; UDP has datagrams; TCP has segments; and for a bit more completeness, Ethernet has frames.

Comment: @user207421 are you sure? "The internet protocol provides for
  transmitting blocks of data called datagrams" - source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc791#section-1.1

Comment: Very good but in common usage it is as I have stated.